# How to run Multiple Process in C#

Tags: c#

Seniors, I am very beginner and new in C# after PHP.

My question is How to execute multiple function same time in c# e.g

```
class void main()
{
 call functionA(argument)
 call functionB(argument)
 call functionC(argument)

// these all function should start at same time
}
```

my first function

```
public void functionA(argument)
{
 richTextbox1.appendText(starttime);
}
```

my second function

```
public void functionB(argument)
{
 richTextbox1.appendText(starttime);
}
```

my third function

```
public void functionC(argument)
{
 richTextbox1.appendText(starttime);
}
```

Your help / guideline will save my time.

Comment: start Googling will save your time, too.

Comment: Dude I already tried but no luck

Comment: Wrap each function into a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task) and start each task.

Comment: Have a look at parallel Tasks......

Comment: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/multithreading/

Comment: oleskssi an Patel. Thanks for your reply. but really I am very new. I hear / read about parallel tasks but could not understand exactly (I accept I am not Sharp) do you have any example / link ?

Comment: Copied your question in google. [First result is this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx)

Comment: @user3559903, why do you think you need to do these things at the same time? All your functions are updating the UI, so it doesn't make sense to run them in parallel.

Comment: You can start reading this maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx and [The Basics of Task Parallelism via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

Comment: Harsh crowd for a beginner, huh?

Comment: @Thomas I am updating UI is just for display start and end time of each process as runtime log only to verify / track functions start and end time.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest option is to use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task) class. Msdn nails it, just copying (with minor edits) the relevant bit here

```
Action action1 = () =>
{
    // your code here
};

Action action2 = () =>
{
    // your code here
};

Task t1 = new Task(action1);
Task t2 = new Task(action2);

t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you Olekssi. I am very thankful to you.

Comment: @user3559903 not a problem. Have a look at the last paragraph of Thomas Levesque's answer. If you need this to update UI, you should probably use `richTextbox1.BeginInvoke` or other `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method.

Answer (score 3):

In general, to do several things in parallel, you need to use threads. The easiest way to do that is through tasks:

```
Task.Run(() => functionA(argument));
Task.Run(() => functionB(argument));
Task.Run(() => functionC(argument));
```

However, in your case, all your functions are trying to update the UI, and only the main thread (UI thread) can do that. So it's definitely not a good use case for multithreading.

Comment: Which will raise another question in few minutes `InvalidOperationException` :(

Comment: I tried in main / button event but it is "saying Error 2 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'"

Comment: @user3559903, I suspect you're targeting .NET 4.0. The Run method was added in 4.5. Instead you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`

Comment: Yes Thomas you're right. Your experience is really Impressive

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search results:

**http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/**

**http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/a/multi-threading-using-task-parallel-library.htm**

By reading this, you will figure out that your code will look similar to this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => functionA("arg"));
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => functionB("arg"));
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => functionC("arg"));
```